# Vanilla JS TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a header with a logo and navigation that has a menu toggle link that displays on smaller viewports. I am try to achieve this with Vanilla JS as I want to move away from jQuery.

When I click on the menu toggle link, I am presented with this error: Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property 'className' of null at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (ignition.js:6) (anonymous) @ ignition.js:6`

I'm currently learning Vanilla JS and I am having a bit of trouble understanding what this means and where the error maybe.

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const navItem = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".nav-item");

    if (navItem.className.includes("active")) {
        navItem.className.remove("active");
        event.target.find("a").innerHTML("<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>");
    } else {
        navItem.className.add("active");
        event.target.find("a").innerHTML("<i class='fas fa-times'></i>");
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-logo"><a href="#"> Ignition <small>Beta</small></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Theme</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I produced the runnable code in the answer below, check out if there's something you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you are clicking on the specific `nav-toggle` element and attempting to use the `querySelector` from it, it's going to return null since no `nav-item` elements exist below it.

It seems like what you would want to do would be to find all of the child elements in your entire menu and apply the necessary logic similar to something like this:

```
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // You'll likely want a reference to your "toggle" element if you need
    // to access it within the loop
    const toggle = event.currentTarget;

    // Get the top level menu
    const menu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

    // Get your menu items and iterate through them
    const menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".nav-item")

    // Iterate through your individual items here
    menuItems.forEach(navItem => {
         // Add your logic here
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe here's the code to achieve what you want: When click the 'nav-toggle' icon:

- Toggle `active` for all nav-item
- Toggle icon of nav-toggle

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  // toggle icon
  const curIcon = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle a i')
  curIcon.classList.toggle('fa-bars')
  curIcon.classList.toggle('fa-times')

  // toggle active of nav-items
  const navItems = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')
  for (const navItem of navItems) {
    navItem.classList.toggle('active')
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-logo"><a href="#"> Ignition <small>Beta</small></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Theme</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

`navItem` is `null` because you're calling `querySelector(".nav-item")` on the current target which is the `<li class="nav-toggle">...</li>` element. That element does not contain any children with class `nav-item`.